# Java Regex to match a specific string or another specific string, or not at all?

Tags: java, regex

Imagine capturing the input with a regex:

```
2.1_3_4
3.2.1
3.2.1.RELEASE
3.2.1.SNAPSHOT
```

The numbers and the dots are easy enough to get

```
([0-9\._]+)
```

But how do you capture that plus "RELEASE" or "SNAPHOT" or none of those?

I played around with the or operator to no avail...

```
([0-9\._]+RELEASE||SNAPSHOT)  // no worky
```

btw, this is a nice regex tester: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
([0-9._]+(RELEASE|SNAPSHOT)?)
```

The (inside) parens form a group, and the question mark indicates the group may occur 0 or 1 times.

Comment: Probably `(?:RELEASE|SNAPSHOT)?` to avoid the inner match group.

Comment: @pickypg Yours would avoid matching the inner match group, but I think the op wants that group. Perhaps the op could clarify.

Comment: Agreed, but based on his original attempt and 'plus "RELEASE" or "SNAPHOT"', I suspect he wants to basically ensure that it passes and get the whole thing. (Though it's worth noting that `...._RELEASE` would match, which he might not expect)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing great. You just need to make a few changes.
First, you do not use `||` for or, `|` is used. So `RELEASE||SNAPSHOT` would convert to `RELEASE|SNAPSHOT`.
Since release or snapshot is not mandatory, a `?` should be placed after it. So the final regex becomes

```
([0-9\._]+(RELEASE|SNAPSHOT)?)
```

You can also use `\d` instead of `0-9`.
else than this, there is no need to escape `.` by `\` when its present inside `[]`
So finally, following could be the final regex

```
([\d._]+(RELEASE|SNAPSHOT)?)
```